# How to implement BM25F,VSM or POS tagging for limited string in python?

Tags: python-2.7, text-files, relevance, pos-tagger, vsm

I have a text file where there are only 35 string i want to find out most relevant string in the text file.How can I implement BM25F,VSM or POS to find it?

e.g

```
Panoramio Bahawalpur
... - Bahawalpur - Picture of Bahawalpur, Punjab Province - TripAdvisor
... Minister Syed Yousaf Raza Gillani\u00e2\u20ac\u2122s short visit to 
Bahawalpur
Bahawalpur Station Pictures - Pakistan in Photos
Noor Mahal Station , Bahawalpur Railway Station | Noor Mahal the italian style palac ...
Bahawalpur Railway Pakistan
Nur Mehal, Bahawalpur
```

given input is **Bahawalpur Railway Station**

How to find most appropriate/relevant strings?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple task you can go with

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
```

it will return you the percentage that how much your string match from

```
def similar(a, b):

  return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
str = "This is hello-hi image"

print "The score of relevancy is :", similar("Hello",str) * 100 ,""
```

You can change the result according to your requirements. Thanks